# Round integer down to nearest 10

Tags: solidity, math, safemath

Is there a good way of floor rounding a number to the nearest 10 in solidity?
I have a function that calculates a percentage of a number but I want only to return multiples of 10. e.g. if it is 12% then it should return 10, if it is 59% then it should return 50.

```
uint256 timeRemaining = block.timestamp - startTimestamp;
uint256 totalStakeTime = dayLength.mul(daySeconds);
uint256 percent = timeremaining.mul(100) / totalStakeTime;
//return 10, 20, 30, 40....90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to floor numbers by a multiple of 10, you can do this with SafeMath.

Approach 1:

```
uint256 num = 59;
return num.div(10).mul(10); // return 50
```

Approach 2:

```
uint256 num = 59;
return num.sub(num.mod(10)); // return 50
```

Note: these 2 approaches should work fine, but the gas cost might be a little different.

Comment: Thanks, which one is cheaper in terms of gas?

Comment: As I tested in Solidity 0.8.17 (without SafeMath), somehow, the 2nd approach is around 15% cheaper.